# PHP isn't reading .bash_profile exports

Tags: php, bash, shell, odbc, environment-variables

For some (not necessarily important) background, I am trying to get a PDO ODBC driver setup on my local vagrant box (using Laravel's homestead box, OS: Ubuntu 16.04) for NetSuite. I got the drivers setup and am exporting the proper environment variables from my `.bash_profile` file:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+":"}${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:-""}
OASDK_ODBC_HOME=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64
ODBCINI=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export OASDK_ODBC_HOME
export ODBCINI
```

`PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` lists odbc and running `isql NetSuite usr psw` connects to the database (without needing to `source /opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini`).

That being said, I can `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the command line and I get a value back, but neither of these commands in PHP return anything:

```
shell_exec('echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

PHP runs under the `vagrant` user which is the same user I log in as on the command line. I've also restarted php7.1-fpm (which is the version of PHP that the script runs under) and nginx. I've also restarted the vagrant box running `vagrant halt` then `vagrant up`.

In the end, the main problem I am trying to overcome is to get PDO to connect to my ODBC database. Running `$pdo = new \PDO('odbc:NetSuite', env('NETSUITE_EMAIL'), env('NETSUITE_PASSWORD'));` throws a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified` exception. If I

```
putenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64');
putenv('OASDK_ODBC_HOME=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64');
putenv('ODBCINI=/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/odbc64.ini');
```

before the `PDO` command then I get a `PDOException: SQLSTATE[01000] SQLConnect: 0 [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/netsuite/odbcclient/lib64/ivoa25.so' : file not found` exception.

Scouring the googleverse has turned up nothing helpful for my particular difficulty. If anyone has any tips, I could move on in my life and be very grateful.

Comment: Are you trying to run PHP commands in bash? ... and your vars aren't working? Or do you think that there is some sort of magic that will allow a PHP file run through nginx to see your exported vars? Unless that bash profile is for the nginx user, I don't see how that's possible.

Comment: @BrianGottier, the PHP script is being run via a HTTP request being handled by nginx. The user that PHP-FPM is running under is the same user where the .bash_profile is stored. I don't see how that is magic.

Comment: then nginx (or whatever the nginx user is called) is the user, not php. I don't know about nginx, but the apache user www-data does not have access to bash as a linux user. Check /etc/passwd probably shows /usr/sbin/nologin

Comment: Nginx is running in a "non-login"-shell and won't trigger `.bash_profile`.